# Discord API Links which one?

Tags: python, api, discord

I have a Python project and I wonder if I should use the:

`https://canary.discord.com/api/v9/`
or
`https://discord.com/api/v9/`

does it make a difference, idk which one to use.

I know that both work, but I don't know the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Canary** is **Discord's alpha testing program.** ... The **Canary** Build's purpose is to allow users to help Discord test new features. Bugs on the **Canary** build are supposed to be reported on the Discord Testers server. Unlike PTB or Stable, **Canary's** icon is orange instead of purple.

So if you are not interested in the **testing program.** You should use `https://discord.com/api/v9/`